# How to include makefile variable in include preprocessor directive

Tags: c, makefile, c-preprocessor

I want to include header files based on makefile variables.

MakeFile

```
DISC     := left
```

Pass this variable to the C program like below:

```
CFLAGS += -DNAME=\"$(DISC)\"
```

In main.c, need to include header for correct disc based on makefile variable.

Is it possible to do

```
#include "NAME_header.h"
```

(where NAME is passed from makefile)

I am getting compilation error
Error: NAME_header.h is not found.

Is this really possible to include header files in this way?

Comment: Please show us what "does not work as expected". Better yet, read [mcve]

Comment: Error: NAME_header.h is not found

Comment: In string literals there is no macro expansion done at any compiling stage.

Comment: Depending on your compiler, you can force the include on the command line.  For example GCC and clang both allow `--include=some_file.h` so you can add that to your `CFLAGS` (or better, `CPPFLAGS`).  Note, however, that these includes happen before any other part of the source file is read in so it won't work if you require them in some other order.

Answer (score 3):

A working solution:

Makefile:

```
DISC := left
CFLAGS += -DNAME=$(DISC)
```

C or C++ source:

```
#define STR(s) STR2(s)
#define STR2(s) #s
#define EXPAND(s) s

#include STR(EXPAND(NAME)_header.h)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution;** consider using a proxy file. See more details below about mixing macros and #include.

In the Makefile, create v_header.h

> echo '#include "${DISC}_header.h"' > v_header.h

Which can be included

> #include "v_header.h"

At this time, the cpp grammer does not allow the usage of macros as part of the '#include' statement. It must be '"path.h"' or ''. The "stringifaction" operators (both '#' and '##') are not processed for pre-processor directives (line starting with '#')

```
// Not working
#include NAME
#include #NAME
#include "#NAME"
#include "##NAME"
```